# Unsetting jQuery element manipulation automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I am manipulating some elements with jquery when the doc is ready and when the window is resized, the problem is I dont want to have to specify to set everything back to normal when the condition does not apply. Here is my code:

```
function portfoliosingle_width(){
    var window_width = $(window).width();
    if(window_width < 964 ){
        $('#portfolio-single #site-main .structure').width(450);
        $('#portfolio-single #site-header').height(100);
        $('#portfolio-single #site-header .structure').width(450);
        $('#portfolio-single-text').width(425);
        $('#portfolio-single-images').appendTo('.structure article');
        $('#logo').css({'display':'block','width':'450px','float':'none'});

    }else if(window_width > 964 ){
        //want everything to go back the way it was without specifying each
    }

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    portfoliosingle_width();
});

$(window).bind("resize", function(){ 
    portfoliosingle_width(); 
});
```

Is there a way to do this without consulting my stylesheet and looking up each value, setting each back to the way it originally was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of specifying width / height in jquery, use css classes, do by adding a class and in else remove that class, it will return to normal

```
$("#myelement").addClass("structure450");
```

and then in else you can do

```
//when you remove the class it will return to normal width and height
$("#myelement").removeClass("structure450");
```

or you can set the width and height to "auto" in else.

after reading you comment, you can do something like this also.

```
//read the html in a variable
var orignalHTML = $("#parentDiv").html();


//in else use this html

else {
  $("#parentDiv").html(orignalHTML);
}
```

Comment: I use this most of the time, however I have 6 elements in this case and what your proposing would just result in me creating more classes then I really need. Plus I'll still be stuck with dealing with undoing that`appendTo`. I was hoping for one end-all solution. However your answer solidified my fears of not having that end-all, thanks.

Comment: This works fantastically. I had to move everything inside of doc.ready though.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your element back to auto:

```
$('#theElement').css('height', 'auto');
```